From Checkerboard graph to any code that snappy supports? planar diagram code dt code gauss code etc
Is there a known way to go from the checkerboard graph of a knot to the planar diagram code? I am using snappy to build a white_graph object and I need to be able to compute the Alexander and Jones polynomials of the underlying knot. I haven't seen support directly for this in snappy (maybe it exists) and would love to know how to do this.
For reference about snappy and white_graph(): https://snappy.computop.org/spherogram.html
